# How padded sequences given as packed sequences are dealt by RNN in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

In pytorch, we can give a packed sequence as an input to the RNN. From [official doc](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html?highlight=lstm#rnn), input of an RNN can be as follows.

> **input (seq_len, batch, input_size)**: tensor containing the features of the input sequence. The input can also be a packed variable length sequence.

Example

```
packed = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(embedded, input_lengths)
outputs, hidden = self.rnn(packed, hidden)
outputs, output_lengths = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(outputs)
```

Here, `embedded` is the embedded representation of a batch input.

My question is, how the computation is carried out for packed sequences in RNN? How the hidden states are computed for padded sequences in a batch through packed representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For the second question: hidden states at padded sequences will not be computed.**

To answer how is that happening, let's first see **what `pack_padded_sequence` does** for us:

```
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence, pad_packed_sequence, pack_padded_sequence

raw = [ torch.ones(25, 300) / 2, 
        torch.ones(22, 300) / 2.3, 
        torch.ones(15, 300) / 3.2 ]
padded = pad_sequence(raw)  # size: [25, 3, 300]

lengths = torch.as_tensor([25, 22, 15], dtype=torch.int64)
packed = pack_padded_sequence(padded, lengths)
```

so far we randomly created a three tensor with different length (timestep in the context of RNN) , and we first pad them to the same length, then **packed** it. Now if we run

```
print(padded.size())
print(packed.data.size()) # packed.data refers to the "packed" tensor
```

we will see:

```
torch.Size([25, 3, 300])
torch.Size([62, 300])
```

Obviously 62 does not come from 25 * 3. So what `pack_padded_sequence` does is only keep the meaningful timestep of each batch entry according to the `lengths` tensor we passed to `pack_padded_sequence` (i.e. if we passed [25, 25, 25] to it, the size of `packed.data` would still be [75, 300] even though the raw tensor does not change). In short, rnn would no even see the pad timestep with pack_padded_sequence

And now let's see what's **the difference after we pass `padded` and `packed` to rnn**

```
rnn = torch.nn.RNN(input_size=300, hidden_size=2)
padded_outp, padded_hn = rnn(padded) # size: [25, 3, 2] / [1, 3, 2]
packed_outp, packed_hn = rnn(packed) # 'PackedSequence' Obj / [1, 3, 2]
undo_packed_outp, _ = pad_packed_sequence(packed_outp)

# return "h_n"
print(padded_hn) # tensor([[[-0.2329, -0.6179], [-0.1158, -0.5430],[ 0.0998, -0.3768]]]) 
print(packed_hn) # tensor([[[-0.2329, -0.6179], [ 0.5622,  0.1288], [ 0.5683,  0.1327]]]

# the output of last timestep (the 25-th timestep)
print(padded_outp[-1]) # tensor([[[-0.2329, -0.6179], [-0.1158, -0.5430],[ 0.0998, -0.3768]]]) 
print(undo_packed_outp.data[-1]) # tensor([[-0.2329, -0.6179], [ 0.0000,  0.0000], [ 0.0000,  0.0000]]
```

The values of `padded_hn` and `packed_hn` are different since rnn DOES compute the pad for `padded` yet not for the 'packed' (PackedSequence object), which also can be observed from the last hidden state: all three batch entry in `padded` got non-zero last hidden state even if its length is less than 25. But for `packed`, the last hidden state for shorter data is not computed (i.e. 0)

p.s. another observation:

```
print([(undo_packed_outp[:, i, :].sum(-1) != 0).sum() for i in range(3)])
```

would give us `[tensor(25), tensor(22), tensor(15)]`, which align to the actual length of our input.

Comment: I emphasize we expect getting zeros because, we expect the RNN to run less than `25` steps. Also to add up to this great answer, at the end, I believe a better last line of code would have been:
`print(undo_packed_outp[-1])` because we do not need to use data (only in the case of packed sequences).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by matthew_zeng of [this relevent question](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/understanding-pack-padded-sequence-and-pad-packed-sequence/4099/5): output are not calculated for the padded elements, and hidden will be the hidden state after the last valid input.